# Minimum path to connect k nodes in a graph with n nodes

Tags: c++, graph, path, nodes, minimum

Given a graph with n nodes and n-1 edges, find the lowest amount of edges needed to connect k nodes. You are given m numbers k <= n for which you have to solve the problem. The edges are unweighted and the graph does not necessarily describe a binary tree.

For a graph with n=5 and k=4, a possible path could be 1-2-5-2-3.

My approach was a greedy method in which I start from the node with the highest rank and try to add edges from there, but I did not have much success in trying to formulate an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find longest path in your tree, you will take every edge on that route once, than choose random node that has an edge, that connect that node to already choosen elements. 
So find longest path in your tree if that path has k or more nodes it is the end, you choose element on that path, every edge will be taken once
 Else choose a random, untaken already node, that is connected by any edge directly to one of already taken nodes, as long as you do not have k nodes in your collection.

Comment: All the nodes are connected by the n-1 edges.

Comment: n-1 edges in graph in whole graph? Sorry, mAybe my English is weak But it seems it is one connected component. If you create any dfs-tree you can choose the longest existing root there, you will take it once, than choose additinal branches/root if you need, you will take them twice. You create dfs-tree in array, where element point to his parent, root to -1, but for this you will need to remember also heigh of every branch. When you choose longest root in the tree, you can add all nodes on that root priority queue, when the prioryty will be longest branch. Still do not know if it 100% correct.

Comment: isn't that graph a tree?

Comment: It is a tree, but not a binary tree; you could have a node with edges to every other node.

Comment: Try to find longest route in your tree, you will take every edge on that route once, than choose random node that has an edge, that connect that node to already choosen elements.
So find longest route in your tree
if that route has k or more nodes it is the end, you choose element on that route, every edge will be taken once
Else choose a random, untaken already node, that is connected by any edge dirctly to one of already taken nodes, as long as you do not have k nodes in your collection.